# AngularJS resourse structure for API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I have structure API:

```
api: {
    users: {
        details: {},
        actions: {}
    },
    settings: {
        users: {}
    }
}
```

for example:

GET /api/users
return list of users

GET /api/users/1
return user with id 1

GET /api/users/1/details
return user deteils

GET /api/users/1/details/photo
return user fetail with alias photo

I wrote

```
.factory('userService', function($resource){
        return $resource('/api/users/:id/:items/:itemsId', {}, {
            query: { method: 'GET', isArray: false }
        });
    });
```

now I can do userService.query() and get list of users
but if I can`t do as this:

```
var users = userService.query();
users[1].name = 'newName';
users[1].save();
```

users[1] don`t save edited info because users[1] don`t have resourse methods, resourse methots isset only users.

And I can`t do as this:

```
var users = userService.query();
users[1].get('deteils');
```

How I can add resourse methods for all my structure?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to prefix instance methods with a $ sign, like `users[1].$save()`.

Then why are you setting `isArray` to `false` but treat the result like an array?

You should also bind the `id` paramter to the id property of your user. I assume it is called `id`.

So you would do something like this:

```
.factory('userService', function($resource){
    return $resource('/api/users/:id/:items/:itemsId', { id: '@id' });
});
```

Note that you have to specify the parameters `items` and `itemsId` in your call, otherwise they will be left out.
e.g.:

```
var users = userService.query();
users[1].name = 'newName';
// assume users[1].id===1
users[1].$save();
// will do a POST /api/users/1

users[1].$get({ items: 'details' });
// will do a GET /api/users/1/details

users[1].$get({ items: 'details', itemsId: 'photo' });
// will do a GET /api/users/1/details/photo
```

PS: Maybe you should also check if the default methods (listed [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource#usage_returns)) fits your REST API, otherwise you should define your own.